# What is the correct way to export a bash function after the shellshock updates?

Tags: bash, redhat, shellshock-bash-bug

I am having problems with a script currently, but I'm not sure of the correct syntax. I think the script was broken with the shellshock patch to bash, but I just want to check.

What is the correct way to export a bash function since the shellshock patch. And what was the correct way before the patch?

Here are a few examples of what I am looking for.

**A.**

```
export BASH_FUNC_module()='() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`\0012}'
```

**B**

```
export BASH_FUNC_module='() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`\0012}'
```

**C**

```
BASH_FUNC_module='() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`\0012}'
export -f BASH_FUNC_module
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to export a function hasn't changed. Define the function, then use `export -f`.

```
func() {
    foo
    bar
}
export -f func
```